# Session value is null servlet doGet at times

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, request

I have the following code

```
<%
  String projectId = request.getParameter("projectId");
  %>
  <iframe width="100%" id="uploadFrame" 
   src="testframe.jsp?projectId=<%=projectId %>"></iframe></body>
</html>
```

and in testframe.jsp I am setting session value as

```
<%
String projectId = request.getParameter("projectId");
 request.getSession(true).setAttribute("prj",projectId);      
 %>
```

and finally in servlet, I am getting session value in doGet method as

```
String prjId = request.getSession(false).getAttribute("prj").toString();
```

Problem I am facing is sometimes session value is null in doGet method, not all the time, although `request.getParameter("projectId")` is not null in testframe.jsp

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You can use `session` [JSP implicit object](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/el/ImplicitObjectELResolver.html) to set the attribute. `session.setAttribute("prj",projectId)`. In servlet same code as above.

Comment: @Aniket In Servlet I have to use HTTPSession object for `session.getAttribute`?